# ifelse function - replacement has length zero R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, subset

I have a dataset `BBB` which is a list and contains `(0,1,2)` values and `Xx` 37232 obs. of 1 variable.

```
head(Xx)
Xx
1           NA
2 0.0006458981
3 0.0014977347
4 0.0021436328
5 0.0018066425



head(BBB)
$`1`
[1] 1 2 0 0 0 0
$`2`
[1] 1 2 0
```

Then I made a rule to get values which according to their positions I am going to subset `Xx` later

```
B<-rep(NA,(length(BBB)-2))
for(i in 1:(length(BBB)-2)){B[i]<-length(BBB[[i]])+as.numeric(which(BBB[[i+1]]==1))}

S<-rep(NA,(length(BBB)-2))
for(i in 1:(length(BBB)-2)){S[i]<-length(BBB[[i]])+as.numeric(which(BBB[[i+1]]==2))}
B<-as.data.frame(B)
S<-as.data.frame(S)
```

So the subset works like following: 
`Xx[B[5,]:S[5,],]`

```
[1] -0.008050324 -0.007825664 -0.008471562 -0.008986408
```

Now I want to make a new rule to save the first value of each subset of `Xx` which is higher or equal to 0.004

For example:

```
which(Xx[B[13,]:S[13,],]>=.0001)
[1] 277 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291
head(which(Xx[B[13,]:S[13,],]>=.0001),n=1)
[1] 277
```

So I wrote the following code:

```
SSS<-rep(NA,length(Xx))
for(i in 2:length(Xx)){SSS[i]<-ifelse(head(which(Xx[B[i,]:S[i,],]>=.004),n=1),
                                  Xx[head(which(Xx[B[i,]:S[i,],]>=.004),n=1),],
                                  tail(Xx[B[i,]:S[i,],]),n=1))}
```

But when applying it I am getting the following error:

`Error in SSS[i] <- ifelse(head(which(Xx[B[i, ]:S[i, ], ] >=  : 
  replacement has length zero`

Comment: What is `Returns`? If it is not defined, than that might well generate this error message.

Comment: syntax: `ifelse(test, yes, no)`
you are inserting a `head(which(Xx[B[i,]:S[i,],]>=.004))` to the test but no actually testing it

Comment: @AndrewGustar it should be `Xx` I forgot to change it.

Comment: You don't give a condition in `ifelse` but a number

Comment: When `i=13` for example, you do `ifelse(277,...)` that can not work.

Comment: @amonk how can I rewrite it so it would be testable?

Comment: @aRo The code needs some revamping.. But you need to tell us what you're thinking you are doing with `ifelse`. simple words that is

Comment: Btw @aRo close but no massage ;)

Comment: let's suppose `Xx[B[i,]:S[i,]] = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,8)`
then `which(Xx[B[i,]:S[i,]]>=4)` = `4,5,6,7`
now I want to store only the first value of the result  `Xx[4]` into `SSS[i]` and if there is no value in `Xx` which is equal or greater than `4` then I want to store `tail(Xx[B[i,]:S[i,]]),n=1))` the last value of the subset in `SSS[i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try this structure for your ifelse statement

```
SSS<-rep(NA,length(Xx))

for(i in 2:length(Xx)){

  SSS[i] <- ifelse(length(which(Xx[B[i,]:S[i,],] >= .004)) > 0,
                   # If there are any values GTE .004, then return the first result GTE .004 
                   Xx[head(which(Xx[B[i,]:S[i,],] >= .004), n=1),],
                   # If there are no values GTE .004, then return the last value of subset
                   tail(Xx[B[i,]:S[i,],]),n=1))
}
```